# Request Header Or Cookie Too Large

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

I am getting **Request Header Or Cookie Too Large** error on firefox on login and checkout pages but on chrome its working fine. I know that it can be fixed by removing cookies for that particular website but i want to know whats causing that issue, so it doesn't come up again.
thanks